# Add ID to canvas drawing for retrieving later on

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the following code to add a circle with text to a canvas:

```
function drawCircle(username, id) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)';
  context.fill();
  context.font = 'bold 8pt Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif';
  context.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
  context.textAlign = 'center';
  context.fillText(username, 100, 105);
}
```

It does work. But is it possible to add the id, so I can interact with the circle later on, with something as canvas['id']?

I'm calling drawCircle multiple times with different usernames and id's.

Comment: What type of interaction you want with the circle element? Do you just want it for the purpose of redrawing everytime for each user?

Comment: Actually is for the possibility of removing them later on and adding ondrop-features to them...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ["Hit Regions"](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#hit-regions) portion of the W3C Canvas spec.

I don't know how widely supported these are, yet, though.  It doesn't appear to be available in Chrome 40.